# Nested loop on GPU with OpenACC returns Segmentation fault

Tags: openacc

there are weeks that I lose my mind with OpenACC! For example I have to parallelize the code

```
float temp;
for( i_v = 0; i_v < ntv; i_v++ )
{
    temp = 0;

    for( i_el = 0; i_el < len_tv; i_el++ )
        temp += pow( tva[i_v*len_tv + i_el], (float)2.0 );

    tv_sq[i_v]=temp;
}
```

to do that, I have tried several ways, the last after the reading of [Nvidia Technology Group](http://on-demand.gputechconf.com/gtc/2012/presentations/S0517B-Monday-Programming-GPUs-OpenACC.pdf) that explains very well the function of gang and vector. So I try:

```
float temp;
#pragma acc data copyin(tva[:nfa]) copyout(tv_sq[:ntv]) create(temp)
{
    #pragma acc kernels loop independent 
        for( i_v = 0; i_v < ntv; i_v++ )
        {
            temp = 0;

            #pragma acc loop independent gang vector reduction(+:temp)
                for( i_el = 0; i_el < len_tv; i_el++ )
                    temp += pow( tva[i_v*len_tv + i_el], (float)2.0 );

            tv_sq[i_v]=temp;
        }
}
```

the compiler said

```
 710, Generating create(temp)
     Generating copyout(tv_sq[0:ntv])
     Generating copyin(tva[0:nfa])
712, Loop is parallelizable
     Accelerator kernel generated
    712, #pragma acc loop gang /* blockIdx.x */
    716, #pragma acc loop vector(128) /* threadIdx.x */
712, Generating present_or_copyout(tv_sq[0:ntv])
     Generating present_or_copyin(tva[0:nfa])
     Generating NVIDIA code
     Generating compute capability 3.5 binary
716, Loop is parallelizable
```

but when I try to execute:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

the same with cuda-memcheck, it answers only segmentation fault. Previously I insert the pragmas in "parallel" ways and not "kernels", but I had problems of "Invalid **global** write of size 8 (...) Out of bounds".

Clearly there is something that I haven't understand, so if somebody can tell me the way to  parallelize these code I'll try to understand my errors

Thank you very very much

Comment: A seg fault almost always indicates a problem in host code, not accelerator code.  Probably you haven't shown enough of what you are doing.  How is `nfa` set, for example?  What version of PGI tools are you using? When I build a simple app (only modifying `nfa`) around the code you have shown, I get [good results](http://pastebin.com/1BNCHqJD).  If you want help, please provide a *complete* application, just as I have shown, along with the compile command and output, and results from running it, just as I have shown.

Comment: discard the pragmas and check whether you still get the segfault. To do this, compile the source code with gcc/g++.